# How to download DRL file to external fileSystem?

Tags: drools

Generating DRL using Jboss Drools DRT.
How to download the generated DRL into an external file system?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Ignore the canned comment immediately previous -- it's clear what you're trying to do.